# How to debug the HTML of a meteor app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, meteor

**TL;DR**: My question is: what is best way to debug the HTML of a meteor app?

I'm a noob who's trying to port an existing HTML theme bought on Themeforest to meteor. The theme is provided in HTML + JS form.

The first step has been to create an HTML page with all the options of the theme configured. I then changed the directory structure and JS libraries organization. This step has been very easy, as I could simply open the HTML page, check which HTML errors popped up, and then either added the CSS/JS or changed the referenced path to match the new folder organization.

I'm now trying to use this HTML with my meteor app. I'm already far ahead, as the page show up with a lot of stuff already working. What doesn’t work are mostly CSS/JS conflicts, which would be easy to fix, if I could check the HTML errors like with plain HTML. Anyhow now the source of the page is mostly a reference to JS libraries, there are no HTML tags, and the chrome console doesn’t show me any meaningful error.

It might be that I'm missing something very basic, maybe I need to install some chrome plugin to help me debug stuff, or I'm misunderstanding something about meteor. What I think is that meteor dynamically generates page, that's why I see mostly JS and no HTML in the source, and a possible solution could be to get a static version of the page from meteor, somehow.

**My question is**: what is best way to debug the HTML of a meteor app?

**Edit note**: I'll explain myself further, to help you understand the scenario: the theme uses Bootstrap. When I created a custom HTML page I upgraded Bootstrap, and I had to change a few references in the code. It was easy because Chrome showed me which properties and assets could not be loaded.

Now I'm using the Meteor Bootstrap CSS package, and the theme broke again. Anyhow, since now I don’t get any errors from the Chrome console, it's very hard to understand what is not working

Comment: in this case or in a generic scenario? What I meant by "debugging HTML" was to have a look at the source so I could check which resources couldnt be loaded.

Comment: hi, you should be using console tools to inspect your HTML, view downloaded resource files etc. In Firefox you can use FireBug, in Chrome you can use the the built in console. Usually you can right click within the browser window and select inspect element to get the developer tools for that browser

Comment: that's what I did with plain html, but now that I'm using meteor HTML is loaded dynamically and I only get javascript when I check the source code.

Comment: But the source code is not the same as dev tools, the source code should looks exactly as your local file as plain text. With dev tools you will see the DOM, your page after styles, javascript and HTML was processed.

Comment: by viewing the source code I meant: right click > view page source, or f12 in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a clear description of what exactly does not work, it is hard to help. However, your problems may be linked to the fact that Meteor "repackage" (not sure if it is the right word) and minify all your CSS and JS files before sending them to the client. 
I had a lot of problems with this recently when I added third parties JS files in my projects. To solve this, and when there is no official Atmosphere package, I put all the JS libraries in client/compatibility. 
Thus, Meteor does not repackage those files and they are loaded on the client before everything else. 
Hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: The stuff in `client/compatibility` is actually loaded first, before other normal JS files. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp